# Accessing environment variables from .env file in springboot on AWS EC2

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I want to set my environment variables in ".env" file for spring boot application that's running on EC2 instance, and access them in code. I know i can set environment variables on EC2 like so

```
export env="dev"
export db.url="xyz"
```

But i dont want to do this, instead i want to maintain these environment variables in a ".env" file and access them in spring boot application like

```
@Value("${env}")
public String env;
```

I'm able to use export and read the env variables but can't get around getting the variables from .env file. I don't want to use shell script either for loading the variables explicitly. Is there a way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you managed to do it locally before deploying to an EC2 instance? Did you try to inject the properties using ".properties" file? It seems like the answer you are looking for.
[spring-boot-application-configuration](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-application-configuration)

If you manage to do it locally, there is not reason you wouldn't be able to do it in an EC2 instance.

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for.. i don't want to use .properties file but .env file, the values used in .properties file is visible to anyone having access to the code.. i'm choosing .env for security purposes

Comment: Assuming that you keep it only in your EC2, perhaps you could make an **additional** .properties file that will not be pushed to any version control service. – Saarett 8 mins ago    Delete